# Army not use OSI model

Tags: osi

I know an old course I had on the network that the army (at least the French army) does not use the OSI model.
This is a 4-layer model (my memory, I'm not sure) and not seven layers as the OSI model.
Someone has this information?
thank you

Comment: There are multiple models. You may mean the TCP/IP model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but you have the names of the other models please

Comment: Just search for `network models`. Some are proprietary.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly, your course was talking about the **TCP/IP model**. This is the model commonly used in networking, and aggregates some of the layers of the ISO/OSI model.

[image]